# GregorianCalendar Class in Java

Tags: java, gregorian-calendar

I am trying to get current time in other time zone. I used this code for this:

```
GregorianCalendar calender = new         
GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Bangkok"));
    System.out.println(calender.getTime());
```

But, when I am running this code, this code provides the current time in CET as the time in my local machine is in CET.
I am confused. Then why there is scope to provide a TimeZone in constructor?

Comment: When this question was asked in 2015, java.time, the modern Java date and time API, had been out for a year. I recommend you don’t use `GregorianCalendar` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. And even less the norious `DateFormat` /`SimpleDateFormat` suggested in a couple of the answers. See [the good answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60236141/5772882).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ahh, the joys of the Java Date/Time API ...

What you want (aside from a better API, such as Joda Time) is a `DateFormat`. It can print dates in a time zone you specify. You don't need `Calendar` for that.

```
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Bangkok"));
dateFormat.format(new Date());
```

---

`Calendar` is for time manipulations and calculations. For example "set the time to 10 AM". Then it needs the timezone.

When you are done with these calculations, then you can get the result by calling `calendar.getTime()` which returns a `Date`.

A `Date` is essentially a universal timestamp (in milliseconds since 1970, with no timezone information attached or relevant). If you call `toString` on a `Date` it will just print something in your default timezone. For more control, use `DateFormat`.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing right now is:

- Getting a calendar in Bangkok time zone
- get the Date object for this time( which is in ms since <s>some date</s> January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT)
- print out this Date in your timezone ([`Date.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString()))

You should use a Formatter class to get the result you want. e.g. [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

An alternative solution would be to use a less confusing Date/Time library. e.g. [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package of Java8

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Bangkok" ) )
```

## *java.time*

The legacy date-time classes you are using are simply terrible, flawed in design and in implementation, built by people who did not understand date-time handling. Avoid those classes entirely.

Use only the modern *java.time* classes defined in [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Bangkok" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Generate text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, wisely extended to append the name of the time zone in square brackets.

```
String output = zdt.toString() ;
```

For other formats, use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) as seen on hundreds of other Questions and Answers.

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/VZKOFi).

> 2020-02-15T12:27:31.118127+07:00[Asia/Bangkok]

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).